# How to efficiently redirect multiple country URLs to mobile sites in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I have the following **working** code:

```
else if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("www.example.de") != -1) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: "https://m.example.de/"});
}
```

The code needs to include all other country websites, for a total of 16 within this specific domain alone - which would look like something like this:

```
else if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("www.example.de") != -1) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: "https://m.example.de/"});
}
else if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("www.example.fr") != -1) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: "https://m.example.fr/"});
}
else if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("www.example.co.uk") != -1) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: "https://m.example.co.uk/"});
}

...

else if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("www.example.it") != -1) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: "https://m.example.it/"});
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this?

Comment: See [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest): it provides the built-in redirection functionality. You may find answers on StackOverflow and elsewhere with examples for webRequestBlocking + redirectUrl. Otherwise this task may be solved using the basic JavaScript string methods like splitting/regexp matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try working with regex groups `()` to match both the url and the extention

```
var d = tabs[i].url.match("(\.example)\.(.*$)");
if(d && d[2]){
    var newUrl = "https://m.example." + d[2];
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: newUrl});
}
```

Comment: Sorry I've just now understood the `d[2]` structure - your answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @quackkkk and Ilya_Gazman : This is not a good RegExp to use to match domains in a URL. It leaves it quite possible that it will have erroneous matches (e.g. `http://www.foo.com/fakeSite/foo.example.tld/the/path/to/some/file`), and potentially permits spoofing your code into matching a URL that has nothing to do with the domain you desire to match. Given that your replacement keeps the TLD, someone could obtain a domain in a TLD which results in you opening their site. You should use a RegExp which matches the entire URL, permitting only the actual domains you desire to match.

Comment: @quackkkk and Ilya_Gazman : If you want, feel free to modify the RegExp in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42888118/3773011). (I've just noticed that the linked answer is down-voted. I'm not sure why. Code works, and the RegExp is effective at only matching domains.) Obviously, you will need to modify the RegExp to fit the code here, but it will not have the possible incorrect matches/replacements which exist with the RegExp that is currently in this answer..

Comment: @Makyen you're right, I've updated the regex to `^[^:]*:(?:\/\/)?(?:[^\.]*\.)?(example\.[^\/]*)`, note the only group `()` here works for my code. Thanks!